# React native image from json

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Hay
I have problem to change image.

```
export const heroImages = [
{
    name: 'Aatrox' ,
    url: './hero/Aatrox.png'
},
{
    name: 'Ahri' ,
    url: './hero/Ahri.png'
},
{
    name: 'Akali', 
    url: './hero/Akali.png'
},
{
    name: 'Akshan' ,
    url: './hero/Akshan.png'
},
]
```

and 2 function:

```
  const chempionNameCheck = async () => {
    const data = await chempionName(chempionId);
    setPlayerChempion(data);
  }
```

```
  const imageDataCheck = async () => {
    if(playerChempion != undefined) { 
      const data2 = await heroImages.filter(data => data.name === 'Akali'); 
      setImageData(data2[0].url);

      if(imageData != undefined && imageData != null){
        setImageLoading(false);
        console.log(imageData)
      }
    }
  }
```

On render i have:

`<View style={chempion.boxImage}><Image style={chempion.image} source={require(imageData)}/></View>`

[but i have error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHc1X.png)

i search information on goole and i don't find anything.

Comment: Can you provide the full screen where you are using all these function please ? Or do an expo snack if possible, but the full file should be enough.